Expected number of failures in the next period T
I'm trying to solve a specific problem and after much search I could not figure it out by myself.
I have a series of observations of failure times of some machines t1, t2, t3... i.e. the total life time of each machine.
Assuming that the experimental data is normal distributed with parameters mu, sigma and a given set of N machines that have been functioning for some time l1, l2, l3, ..., ln.
Can the question, which is the probability of failure for each machine in the next period of time T be answered ?
I know what to expect. For new machines ( short l times ) the probability of failure should be low and for longer l times indicating older machines I should get high probability of failure tending to 1 but I could not come up with a solution.
I tried using Bayes theorem but I'm lost.

I guess the machine with the current lifetimes ($l_1$, $l_2$, etc) are not the same machines you have the failure data for?

This is an inapplicable model and does not provide enough information.  Typically, you want to model the probability distribution of the time to the next failure of any given machine.

@GeorgeSavva Yes, the machines that failed are "gone" and we have some machines that are still working with lifetimes l.


Assuming that the experimental data is normal distributed with parameters mu, sigma and a given set of N machines that have been functioning for some time l1, l2, l3, ..., ln.

This is an unnecessary assumption that doesn't quite make sense, and pointing out why might be somewhat instructional.
For starters, data can not be normally distributed, or distributed in any other way for that matter - data is just a collection of numbers. It can be viewed as arising from a distribution, or as a realization of some stochastic process, but a distribution is something associated with the random process that gave rise to the data, while data is just a list of numbers.
With that distinction clear, a normal model is almost never appropriate for time-to-event data. Assuming your observed failure times arise from a normal distribution, you're assuming that your times can range from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, which doesn't make much sense (how do you interpret a negative expected time-to-failure?). On top of that, distributions of waiting times tend to be much more long/heavy tailed than what you assume in a normal model.

Can the question, which is the probability of failure for each machine in the next period of time T be answered ?

Sort of, with some assumptions. As indicated in the comments to your original post, the general modeling strategy is to model the probability that any one machine fails within a certain period of time, and this is generally done without making strong distributional assumptions. Extending that to a question about multiple machines is a straightforward exercise.
The modeling of time-to-even data falls under the purview of a field of statistics called survival analysis. If you'd like to learn more about these methods, there are a lot of very good introductory resources floating around out there.
I can walk through some of the basic ideas about how these ideas could apply to the situation you're describing. First, some assumptions:

There are two kinds of machines: those that have failed, and those that haven't failed yet.
For any machine $m_i$ where we observe failure at time $t_i$, we have the time-to-failure (or 'lifetime' as you put it)
For any machine that has not failed yet at time $t_k$, we know that its time-to-failure is at least $t_k$. We call these observations right-censored.

Note the emphasis in that last point. The entire idea behind survival analysis is that we're looking at the amount of time until something inevitable happens, which makes it very appropriate in contexts like medicine and mechanical reliability. The idea is to leverage the fact that we have some information about the time-to-event from those observations where we haven't actually observed a failure, in the form of a lower bound on that time.
Now onto some light math: given some event, the probability that it has not occurred yet at time $t$ is given by the survival function $S(t) = P(T > t)$. From here we can observe that the probability that an event has occurred by time $t$ is given by $1-S(t)$.
In this case, you expressed interest in the probability that a failure occurs in some interval $[t_1,t_2]$, conditional on the fact that this event has not yet occurred at time $t_1$. This last little bit of information is subtle, and important. To study this, we generally look at something called the hazard function $\lambda(t)$, which is the 'instantaneous' risk of failure at time $t$.
If this is ringing some calculus bells, that's good because it is very closely related to the derivative of the survival function (see any of the above resources for more mathematical details). To find the probability that you observe an event within that interval $[t_1,t_2]$, you can simply integrate the hazard function across that interval to get the cumulative hazard.
That's all on paper, of course. In practice (e.g. you have real actual data and need to estimate these quantities with some uncertainty bounds), then the most common estimator for survival functions is the nonparametric Kaplan-Meier estimator, while the most common nonparametric estimator for cumulative hazard is probably the Nelson-Aalen estimator. For modeling the associations between covariates and failure risk, the cox proportional hazards model is popular.

Thank you for your detailed answer! I'll look into the resources you provided.
